# numpy mask covers another mask

Tags: numpy, mask, numpy-ndarray

I have different masks from different shapes in an image. Since some of the shapes contain other shapes, I would like to check if a given mask covers another given mask. For instance consider the followings:

`A=[True, True, True, True, True,
    True, False, False, False, True,
    True, False, False, False, True,
    True, False, False, False, True,
    True, True, True, True, True]`

`B=[False, False, False, False, False,
    False, True, True, False, False,
    False, True, True, False, False,
    False, False, False, False, False,
    False, False, False, False, False]`

In a 5x5 image, A covers B. How can I check if A covers B?

EDIT:
A and B could also share some points and A still covers B:

`A=[True, True, True, True, True,
    True, False, False, False, True,
    True, False, False, False, True,
    True, False, False, False, True,
    True, True, True, True, True]`

`B=[False, False, False, False, False,
    True, True, True, False, False,
    True, True, True, False, False,
    False, False, False, False, False,
    False, False, False, False, False]`

Comment: Are both A and B of same shapes? If not, how do you define "cover"?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "cover" the answer is almost certainly [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.bitwise.html)

Comment: @Divakar Yes. They're both of a same shape coming from Mask-RCNN model.detect()

Comment: And `A` always has a closed surface and we are always looking for the True ones off `B` inside the corresponding shape in `A`?

Comment: @DanielF Thanks. Do you mean something like this: invert(B) , then C = bitwise_and(A, B) and finally check if C == A? What if B edge is on A? I mean both matrices share a same column or row with True?

Comment: @Divakar Yes. Exactly. Both have close surfaces. However, B might not be exactly inside A. It might overlap A in some directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could fill holes for `A` to have a blob and then perform `OR-ing`  with `B`. If the `OR-ing` results in the same array as the holes-filled `A`, it concludes `A` as the "cover". To fill holes, we can use [`SciPy's binary_fill_holes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_fill_holes

Af = binary_fill_holes(A)
out = (Af == Af | binary_fill_holes(B)).all()
# or np.array_equal(Af, Af | binary_fill_holes(B))
```

Comment: Thanks! binary_fill_holes is exactly what I need.